# how to connect two viewcontrollers to same navigationcontroller in storyboard iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I am doing an application where i can check for a condition in Appdelegate class as follows:-

`if([array count] == 0) {one viewController} else{another viewController}`

How will i do this in storyboard like i'm asking the connection so that the corresponding viewcontrollers are displayed.

I'm new to iphone development.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do this is:

1. Create a regular UIViewController: this will be your root view controller.
2. Create the 2 other UIViewControllers.
3. Create 2 segues from the root view controller in step #1 to the 2 in step #2.
4. Put your condition check in the viewDidAppear: launch the appropriate segue based on your condition.
5. Embed the root view controller in a navigation controller (go to the **Editor** menu in Xcode and then select **Embed In**).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable idea

Comment: What kind of segue should be created in step 3? Presenting, or triggered? Push or modal?