# IOS: how to handle view controllers at first Login ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i first come to Login Screen I store value in `NSUserDefaults`. When I press on `signinButtonAction` to move to `DetailScreen` it stucks and never moves forward.
I have made `DetailScreen` embedded in `Navigationcontroller` as `InitialViewController` even the next screen is not navigating to other screens when i re-run it again it comes to `DetailScreen` and then `DetailScreen` stucks to navigate to other screens.

How do I handle this?

My code is here:

`AppDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        categoryVC *viewController = (categoryVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"categoryVC"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
    }
    else
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        signInVC *viewController = (signInVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signInVC"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:viewController];
    }
```

in `SigninButtonAction` I am doing:

```
{
    categoryVC * second= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"categoryVC"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Besides NickCatib's good suggestion, which does not address your issue, did you check that self.storyboard actually has a value different from nil?

Comment: BTW, you should not cast signInVC to categoryVC. it does not matter in this case because UIViewController would to. (no cast requried). Plus your class names should always start with an upper case letter.

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot of your storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not set `RootViewController` if you have such a workflow. I would instantiate main view controller as is, and if you need to show auth I would use `presentViewController`. Later on, you can do dismiss or something like that.

So, in you app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if (nil == [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        categoryVC *viewController = (categoryVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signInVC"];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    }
}
```

and then, when you do the auth and it passes:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Comment: well How do i do this in app delegate??

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (nil == [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        categoryVC *viewController = (categoryVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"signInVC"];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    }
 }

Comment: Thnx user289... I have network issue and will update answer.  When you do the auth you can call [self dismissViewController]. I am on phone so I think there is animated parameter. Will post correct syntax as soon as I am at the computer

Comment: Edited. Let us know if you were able to do it.

Comment: Thnx @user2894531  , It started working for next viewcontrollers but my login Screen has skipped when i removed and reinstalled it on my testing device

Comment: You should do "Reset content and Settings" for simulator and try again.

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present <signInVC: 0x15541c30> on <UINavigationController: 0x1565d1e0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: I am getting an 'id' as response from Server in signIn which is missing now so I can't work on it further, but it was working previously

Comment: Yeah, after I took a look on your storyboard I see that your navigation controller is not connected with Auth. I usually use separate storyboards for different workflows. Here is help for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446046/how-to-connect-two-viewcontrollers-to-same-navigationcontroller-in-storyboard-ip. Regarding id issue, are you certain that you are calling server now ?